# How to handle put requests in Finatra?

Tags: scala, finagle, twitter-finagle, finatra

I have a service which has a put endpoint. I want to be able to access the url param as well as the body.
How do I achieve this.

This is my endpoint:

```
put("/:customerNum") { foo: Foo =>
    val custNum = ???
  }
```

How do I access customerNum ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here how you can extract things related to [request](https://twitter.github.io/finagle/docs/com/twitter/finagle/http/Request.html):

```
put("/:customerNum") { request =>
      // Get request body
      val body = request.getContentString
      // Get content type
      val contentType = request.contentType
      // Get customer number
      val customerNum = request.routeParams.get("customerNum")

      println(s"Customer number: ${customerNum}. Content Type: $contentType. Body: $body")
      render.plain("ok").toFuture
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
put( / string) { (customerNumber: String) =>
    s"$customerNumber!"
  }
```

Comment: This way I won't have access to the "foo" object. I want both the foo object and the url parameter